# How to set App Specific Timezones

Tags: applications, cyanogenmod, 4.2-jelly-bean, root-access, time-zones

So I downloaded a new app, but it only works for US Timezones. I live in the UK, and I don't want to either keep my phone on US Timezones or switch it every time I want to use it. I have an Android, running Cyanogen 4.2.2.

Is there any way that the phone automatically switch timezone every time the app is launched, or trick the app into thinking my timezone is US when it's actually UK?